# $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=f(x,y)\}$ is a surface with a single atlas $(\mathbb{R}^2, Id_{\mathbb{R}^2})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

**If $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f: U\to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$, then $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=f(x,y)\}$ is a surface with a single atlas$(\mathbb{R}^2, Id_{\mathbb{R}^2})$.**

I am beginning to study and surfaces and I am trying to understand many things that I had not seen before. So I would like someone to explain to me why what I put up is a surface with all the details, thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by ***a surface with a single letter***, care to explain?  Cheers!

Comment: Explaining why this is the way it is may be helped if you supply your definitions: this way, those writing answers know where to aim at.

Comment: Letter = atlas? Chart?

Comment: @Randall: I think chart. There is never a single atlas :)

Comment: @RobertLewis I already edited that

Comment: Multiple issues: 1. If you just want to show that $S$ is a smooth manifold, you won't even need that $f$ is $C^\infty$, but only mere continuity of $f$, because even in such case, $S$ has the same topology as $U$ and hence a single chart gives $S$ a smooth structure. What you may want to show is rather that $S$ is a smooth submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$. 2. The chart you want would not be $(\Bbb R^2, Id_{\Bbb R^2})$, because $S$ is always not $\Bbb R^2$ itself. ($S$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$!) Why would you use the identity function on $\Bbb R^2$, whose domain and codomain not a subset of $S$?